# Not Equal to Query in 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I want to Get the location name from location table 
which is not equal to the id present in user location
I have following two tables

1) **Master Data**

```
Empno| EmpName | UserLocation
123456| Sabeeh   | 654
325641| Arsalan  | 500
```

2) **Locations**

```
Loc_id| Location 
 654  | Tando Alam
 544  | Dakhni Oil Plant
```

I want an Sql Query For this Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all records from the master table whose Loc_id does not exists in the locations table with a NOT EXISTS condition and a correlated subquery :

```
SELECT m.*
FROM master m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM locations l WHERE l.Loc_id = m.UserLocation
)
```